# Ember jQuery "one" event handler getting called more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In my Ember app, I have some jQuery code to execute (based on paste to an input box)

My question is I have used "one" in my code, but it is getting executed more than once. As per jQuery docs, it should be invoked only once.

```
didRender: function() {
    var self = this;
    var $inputs = Ember.$("input[id*=my-field]");

    $inputs.on("paste", function() {
        var $this = Ember.$(this);
        var originalValue = $this.val();
        $this.val("");

        $this.one("input", function() {
            // Why is this getting invoked more than once ?
            // Contains code which splits & sets value to multiple textboxes like 
//$inputBox.val('SPLITTED_PASTED_VALUE');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It gets invoked the number of times that you call `.one` - as it's inside *another* event handler, you'll get a new event every time you paste.

Comment: Actually that is not the case with pure jQuery if you see http://jsfiddle.net/D7jVR/

Issue is only if I try to use with Ember

Comment: `.one` gets run once - if you call `.one(..)` then `.one(..)` again before the first has run, then you get it twice.   See http://jsfiddle.net/D7jVR/1048/  (console.log on button click)  It might not be the issue/cause here, but the principal stands "in pure jQuery".

Comment: Not really sure why you need the `.one` anyway - just continue the code?  or use a `setTimeout`.

Comment: So what I want is if the pasted value is not of a certain length, I want to revert back to the old value (which was there in the texbox)

Comment: I don't know ember but this part looked strange `var $this = Ember.$(this)` . Is it can be `var $this = Ember.$(self)`  instead ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're seeing this issue is because EVERY TIME ember re-renders your component/view, it re-executes the didRender hook.

Because the input elements you're attaching jquery events to are persisting across renders, the events keep getting added.  `.one()` does execute only one time, as expected, but you've actually applied the `.on('paste')` multiple times, meaning that every time you paste in, `.one()` is added one more time.

My ultimate reccomendation - stop using jquery.  Mixing jquery and ember together causes weird things to happen that are harder to track down.

If that's not possible, then change how the on-paste event is called.
It's most likely that your textbox is rendered only one time, when the component/controller is loaded.
If that's the case, use the [didInsertElement](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/Component/events/didInsertElement?anchor=) to apply jquery listeners to the elements.

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    var self = this;
    var $inputs = Ember.$("input[id*=my-field]");

    $inputs.on("paste", function() {
        var $this = Ember.$(this);
        var originalValue = $this.val();
        $this.val("");

        $this.one("input", function() {
            //Manipulations here
        });
    });
}
```

Also, consider if you even need the `one('input')` event.  It appears to execute immediately after pasting, so you might be able to remove that and just handle your manipulations after emptying the value.